# What is the easyest way to transform the In.ReadInts function from Java to C#?

Tags: java, c#

I have the following code:

```
public class Search
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] whiteList = In.readInts(args[0]);

        while(!StdIn.Empty())
        {
            int key = StdIn.readIn();
        ...
        }
    }
%java Search largeW.txt < largeT.txt
```

How to transform it to C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
Console.WriteLine("Input your number: "); // input 4, press enter
var theVar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // theVar is 4
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What can I do if we have some file with numbers in input? Not just the one number, how to store this number to array?

Comment: Here you are: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) to deal with file.

Answer (score 1):

Java and C# aren't too different. You just need to know how to read `STDIN`, right? For a console application, use `Console.ReadLine()` or one of the [other methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by the `Console` class.

Also keep in mind when converting:
1. With method names, you capitalize the first letter of EVERY word, i.e. `MyMethod()`. (important because `Main()` needs to be capitalzed)
2. All classes are inside a `namespace` block.
3. All of your type conversion tools are under [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
4. [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a static class. You don't create instances of it like in Java. I recommend looking at `File.ReadAllLines(string name)`.

Other than that the syntax is very similar and it should be fairly easy to convert between the two languages.